# Why when I train a network model multiple times I get different trained models and different results?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Why when I train a network model for the same options and the same database I get different trained models and in results, I have different classification of results.

> 1) I have a loop to train n-times neural network models
>
> 2) I set the same training options
>
> 3) I have the same database to train and test
>
> 4) I use the same pre-trained model (for example google net)

And finally, every time (n=1,2,3) I have different results of classification. The differences are even equal to 10 percentage points

---

database - face images (always reading the same database not randomly)
models - i have used models pretrained from Matlab and pre-trained on only face images from github.

```
opts = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'MaxEpochs',1, ... %5  50
    'MiniBatchSize',100,... %64  10
    'InitialLearnRate',5e-5,... 
    'ExecutionEnvironment','gpu',...
    'Shuffle','every-epoch', ...
    'Plots','training-progress');
```

If some options are not identified it is means that are default.

Comment: What is the data about? What are the features of your training dataset? Is the accuracy of the classification also fluctuating?

Comment: Database is face images from infrared range. Finally when i use  classify function I get diffrent reults for the models which was training in the same way.

Comment: And for example first model i have 85 accuracy, second model (the same training an the same model and the same training dataset) i get result about 76.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not completely defined by the parameters you mention. 
In addition there are **random seeds** involved. When you use pretrained models you should reinitialize the last few layers. Using the complete pretrained parameters can often lead to convergence to bad local minima.

Maybe you do that already, then the randomness comes from there. Additionally i assume you train batchwise. If you dont specify a random seed, the batches for each run are different, because the instances, which each batch contains, are chosen according to a random seed.

Presenting training instances to a NN in different orders leads to different results.

Comment: I have changed my last layers (classification and fully connected).
How to change matlab to take the same seed groups.

Comment: use 'rng(0)', more info here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html

Comment: At the start of your script

Comment: To speed up the calculations I have changed the base (still face thermal face images) and options, however, I used rng (0) as instructed. And of course I taught and tested the same for three times with the same database etc... I received the following results from the classify function: 83.62% (first obtained training model), 82.85% (second obtained training model), 83.29% (third obtained training model)

Comment: But I also checked what I have already analyzed earlier. It turns out that when you change the LearningRate options from 3e-5 to 3e-3, the results are more diverse. 71.24%, 66.95%, 63.74%

Propably the second research shows me that model is underfitted.So LearningRate has not influece to my diverse of scores.